# how to delete a file started with '-'

Tags: linux, command, rm

How can I delete a file whose name started with '-'?

For example, if I have a file named -a and I delete it with:

```
    rm -a
```

I will get:

```
    rm: invalid option -- 'a'
    Try 'rm --help' for more information.
```

So how can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try like this:

```
rm ./-foo
rm ./-filename
rm -- -foo
```

Answer (score 1):

rm "\-a" worked on my Mac, try again please

Comment: still not working! I'm using 10.5.4. maybe it is too old for that :)

Comment: mmm, try "rm -- -a" then

Answer (score 0):

use `unlink` command:
 `unlink -a...`

Answer (score 0):

`--` indicates the rest are arguments, not options.

`rm -- -a`

Answer (score 0):

You can still get away with rm by saying:

rm ./-a

Answer (score 0):

If you have GNU versions of `rm` or `unlink`, you can delete the file with:

```
rm -- -a
```

or

```
unlink -- -a
```

The `--` tells it to stop processing command-line arguments and treat a leading `-` as a literal.